# Completely hiding nginx server response header

Tags: nginx

I'm having trouble hiding my server header (nginx 1.2.1).

I've google'd it and it seems all I have to do is to set `server_tokens off;` in nginx.conf. But doing this only removed the version number, but it still shows nginx as the server.

I've seen there's a module called [HttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule) but I don't need all those fancy options. All I want is to hide the header.

How can I manually hide the header completely?

Comment: Hiding the header does not get rid of security problems. You would do much better to keep nginx up to date.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it wasn't the latest release. I assumed it would be, I'll update it later.

Comment: There is not only security: removing `Server` header also removes a few extra bytes from your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use the module to remove the header then you will have to modify the source to not send it. There's no option in nginx to not send the nginx server header. On a side note, removing the header probably won't prevent people from figuring out you use nginx as each server has certain behaviours that can be probed.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll have to use the module. And I know about the fingerprinting software issue's. I've got a question about that here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/defend-against-http-fingerprinting You're free to help if you know any solutions. :)